# JComponentRouterView not found .... when unit testing Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, troubleshooting, unit-testing

I want to start unit testing my own joomla library and components. So I downloaded tests folder and phpunit.dist.xml file from [Github](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms). Then I copied those files to joomla directory(renamed phpunit.xml.dist to phpunit.xml). Directory structure is now like this:

```
joomla/
     administrator/
     bin/
     cache/
     ..
     ..
     tests/
     configuration.php
     index.php
     ...
     phpunit.xml
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'JComponentRouterView' not found in C:\...joomla\tests\unit\suites\libraries\cms\component\router\stubs\JComponentRouterViewInspector.php on line 18.
```

I'm using netbeans. Even if I run phpunit from command line I get the same error. Its been almost 2 days and I'm stuck.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: maybe we need a new tag "unit-testing" or similar